# Keep receiving error: access of undefined property menu in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I am following a tutorial (http://flashdeveloptutorial.blogspot.com/2011/08/chapter-2.html) for AS3 using flash develop to create a pong clone and am having trouble with displaying a main menu. I previously had a functioning prototype with a moving paddle so I believe the error(s) is in my revised(or new) Main, MainMenu, PongGame or CustomEvents file(s). When I run the code as instructed through the tutorial I receive the error ; access of undefined property menu in my Main.as file:

```
 package 
    {
        import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author 
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        private var game:PongGame;
        ****private var menu:MainMenu;****

    public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

        }

        private function buildMenu():void {
            menu = new MainMenu();
            addChild(menu);
            menu.addEventListener(CustomEvents.LAUNCH_GAME, startGame, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function startGame(e:CustomEvents):void {
            removeChild(menu);
            menu.removeEventListener(CustomEvents.LAUNCH_GAME, startGame);
            menu = null;
            game = new PongGame();
            addChild(game);
        }
    }
    }
```

So I added the "private var menu:MainMenu;" section but I do not know what class/ .as file to reference? or how to define var menu:

Sorry for the large amount of attached code. I did not change paddle.as which is the longest file.

### assets.as

```
package 

{
    public class Assets  
    {
        [Embed (source = '../lib/paddle.png')] public static const Pad:Class;
    public function Assets(): void {

        }
    }

}
```

### Paddle.as

```
package 

{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    public class Paddle extends Sprite {
        private var pic:Bitmap = new Assets.Pad();
        public function Paddle():void {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, go);
        }
        private function die(e:Event):void {
            removeChild(pic);
            pic = null;
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
            removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, die);
        }

    private function go(e:Event) : void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, go);
        addChild(pic); 
            y = stage.stageHeight - pic.height;
            x = stage.stageWidth * .5 - pic.width * .5;
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, die);
        }

    private var movingLeft:Boolean; 
    private var movingRight:Boolean;

    private function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
        if (movingLeft) {
            if(x-speed >= 0) {
                x -= speed;
        }
            else {
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (movingRight) {
            if (x + speed + pic.width <= 600) {
                x += speed;
            }
            else {
                x = 600 - pic.width;
            }
        }
    }
    private var speed:int = 10;



    private function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 87) {
        if  (!movingLeft) {
            movingLeft = true;
            }
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 83) {
            if (!movingRight) {
                movingRight = true;
                }
            }
        }


    private function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 87) {
            if (movingLeft) {
                movingLeft = false;
            }
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 83) {
            if (movingRight) {
                movingRight = false;
            }
        }

    }

    }
    }
```

### mainmenu.as

```
package 

{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class MainMenu extends Sprite
    {
        private var pongButton:Sprite;

        public function MainMenu():void{
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, go);
        }

        private function go(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, go);
            pongButton = item("Play", 20, 30, launchGame, 0xFF0000);
            addChild(pongButton);
        }

        private function launchGame(e:MouseEvent):void {
            dispatchEvent(new CustomEvents(CustomEvents.LAUNCH_GAME));
        }

        private function item(buttonText:String, X:int, Y:int, Funct:Function, txtColor:uint = 0xFFFFFF):Sprite {
            var item:Sprite = new Sprite();
            item.graphics.beginFill(0);
            item.graphics.lineStyle(1, txtColor, .5);
            item.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 250, 30);
            var myText:TextField = new TextField();
            myText.selectable = false;
            myText.width = 250;
            myText.height = 30;
            item.addChild(myText);
            myText.autoSize = "center";
            myText.text = buttonText;
            myText.textColor = txtColor;
            item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Funct);
            item.x = X;
            item.y = Y;
            return item;
        }

    }

}
```

### PongGame.as

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class PongGame extends Sprite
    {
        private var paddle:Paddle;

        public function PongGame():void {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, go);
        }

        private function go(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, go);
            paddle = new Paddle();

            addChild(paddle);
        }
    }

}
```

### CustomEvents.as

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class  CustomEvents extends Event
    {
        public static const LAUNCH_GAME:String = "launch_game";

        public function CustomEvents(e:String):void {
            super(e);
        }

    }

}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If all classes reside in the same package, your code should work.  What error do you receive after adding menu?  Also note your "CustomEvent.as" class should be: "CustomEvents.as"

Comment: Events was a typo error, fixed. I don't receive an actual error but nothing but my background displays. The tutorial I am using did not have the *'d var menu and that is when I received an error. So, I added the var menu but nothing displays and I'm not sure if I did it correctly

Comment: Not an error, simply nothing displays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've correctly added the menu property, the menu is never displayed because `buildMenu()` function is never called.

From your main class `init()`, call `buildMenu()` to instantiate and add `menu` to the stage:

**Main.as**

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    // entry point
    buildMenu();
}
```

Comment: Works now! I thought that buildMenu was never called was odd but didn't know where to call it. Must be an error in my tutorial. Thanks!